# How to spec CarrierWave MiniMagick manipulate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, minimagick

Having troubles writing RSpec tests for my implementation of "auto_orient" on my CarrierWave uploader. Im also not finding much love on the matter online.

I understand that the manipulate method would be specced by the gem, but Im just wanting to validate that my ImageUploader is implementing it correctly with RSpec.

```
    class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
      include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

      ...

      version :tile do
        process :auto_orient
      end

      # Fix images being uploaded the wrong orientation
      def auto_orient
        manipulate! do |img|
          img = img.auto_orient
        end
      end



    let(:uploader) { ImageUploader.new(profile, :avatar) }

    before do
      ImageUploader.enable_processing = true
      File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/support/images/logo.png')) { |f| uploader.store!(f) }
    end

    after do
      ImageUploader.enable_processing = false
      uploader.remove!
    end

    xit 'runs auto_orient on the image' do
      # ???
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how to do this in MiniMagick exactly, but here's how I approached the problem using RMagick if that helps. Should be a similar approach I would think.

```
uploader.cache_stored_file!
# For minimagick, you would probably use MiniMagick::Image::read
mg = ::Magick::Image::read(uploader.file.file).first
# Not sure if minimagick has an "orient" attribute, might try reading the data using something from here instead: https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick/blob/master/lib/mini_magick.rb#L204
expect(mg.orientation.to_i).to eq(1)
```

Comment: Looks good, but getting this error when trying to read the `uploader.file.file`: `MiniMagick::Invalid: identify /var/folders/69/z1zmxlt50w3_fs9_pb3mr0ph0000gn/T/mini_magick20180301-54539-18z3sdj failed with error:
identify: no decode delegate for this image format ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/554.`